# When auto-submitting a form, how do I add a header?

Tags: jquery, header, form-submit

I’m using JQuery 1.9.2, although this question might not concern JQuery.  I’m auto-submitting an HTML form using this code …

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#autolaunch').submit(); 
    }); 
</script>
…
<form id="autolaunch" name="autolaunch" action="${ltiLaunchUrl}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="lti_version" value="${lti_version}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lti_message_type" value="${lti_message_type}" />
    …
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_name_given" value="${lis_person_name_given}" />
</form>
```

The action of the form is a different domain than the server on which this page is accessed.  My question is, how can I add a header when submitting this data?  The header I want to add would look like name = "LTI-Authorization" and value = “Token consumerKey:consumerSecret”.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add a header to a form.

Instead of header add a new hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="LTI-Authorization" value="Token consumerKey:consumerSecret" />
```

You can add header by using ajax request or XHR.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "LTI-Authorization":"Token consumerKey:consumerSecret"
    },
    data: {
       "lti_version":"${lti_version}" // all other data
    }
}).done(function(data) { 
    alert(data); 
});
```

Comment: Does this make the outgoing request look the same as if the header were added?

Comment: @DaveA No it is not the same. You have to check the input value in the backend instead of headers. You can use ajax request to add the header, see the updated answer.

Comment: Also I didn't think you can submit an AJAX request to a different domain than the domain from which the AJAX request is originating.  Is this true?

Comment: If that domain allows you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085965/jquery-ajax-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: What if you don't want to use ajax but need to redirect to where the form post.  Not everything is ajax.

Comment: @Sam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516865/how-to-set-a-header-field-on-post-a-form

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header in Jquery just that needs taking a handle of the `javascript` [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object while you do a [Jquery form submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-handler). I have answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58965526/1909708).
You'd be doing something like this:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "/v1/target-endpoint.do", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("custom_header", "test value of custom header");
xhttp.send($("#custom_form").serialize());
```

where xhttp is your `XMLHttpRequest` object.