# JQuery form submit adding request headers

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I want to ask is it possible to specify headers before calling `$(myForm).submit();` I know you can specify in AJAX post request but is it possible before this simple form submit ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to add headers to a regular form submit using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Requires some native `JavaScript` drudgery, this is how I did it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <h1>Custom Header Injection 1</h1>
    <div id="header_demo">
      <form id="custom_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="name_1" value="${form.name_1}" />
        <button type="button" onclick="submitFormAndHeader()">Submit Form</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function submitFormAndHeader() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
              this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "/v1/target-endpoint.do", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("custom_header", "test value of custom header");
        xhttp.send($("#custom_form").serialize());
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Added a function `submitFormAndHeader` which creates an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object that adds the required headers and submits a `HTML` `DOM` form via `HTTP POST`.

---

Alternatively, you can use [Jquery submit handler](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-handler) and invoke the `submitFormAndHeader()` function created above:

```
$( "#custom_form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  submitFormAndHeader();
});
```

Comment: OP asked without Ajax

Comment: Hi @epascarello, yes XMLHttpRequest.send() is indeed an ajax call. However, original question was: 
`is it possible to specify headers before calling $(myForm).submit();`
Here, we're adding a header during a form submit event and overriding it's default behaviour.

Comment: Yes it has nothing to do with Ajax.... Answer is.... not possible

Comment: @epascarello I have explained it is possible to add headers while calling `$(myForm).submit();` .. i.e. by passing a overriding `$( "myForm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {...`

.. without using jquery's ajax function as was asked by @Donatas:
    `$.ajax({      headers: {        custom_header: 'test value of custom header'      },...`

Comment: Ajax Headers is not going to do anything with a normal form submission. It will only make a difference if they make an Ajax Call.

Comment: yes, `$(myForm).submit();` is converted to an ajax request by customizing its default behaviour. Please try the code.